# C# "shared pointer" for alternative memory management?

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to do this in C#:

1. an Asker object will ask a Giver object for Resource objects.
2. when asked, Giver will search it's Dictionary for existing matching Resource. If found, it will return the reference of the Resource; otherwise, it will create a the new Resource from database data, save that reference in Dictionary, and finally return the reference.
3. the Asker may ask for the same Resource more than once, in which case Giver will return the same Resource from the Dictionary the same number of times.
4. the Asker may at any time have no use for a given Resource, in which case, it does nothing further to the Resource.
5. Problem: How can Giver detect for any Resource that it is no longer in use and remove it from the Dictionary? Preferably, Giver should do this without Asker's help.

Is this possible? I can't seem to solve this.

EDIT:
Thanks everyone for the great replies. Especially the WeakReferences. I didn't know they were there. But I have 2 main objectives which I could have specified clearer.

1. Giver should not rely on Asker to get notified.
2. While a given Resource is in use, *all* of the references must be pointing to the same Resource so that modification to the Resource is reflected in all places where the same Resource is used.

EDIT:
[Removed incorrect code block]

Comment: Sounds like garbage collection

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I have edited my post to include more specific contraints. Hope to get your feedback.

Comment: The class you've come up with won't actually solve the issue, since you hold on to a reference to the instance within your class. Take a look at the answer that I provided; it performs the necessary isolation using `WeakReference` in the cache and returns only a single instance of the resource to the asker. As with all solutions, it's not guaranteed to clean up anything (since your object may not, in fact, ever get garbage collected), but if it does, it will.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for your response. I have added my comments to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, what you're talking about is the basic idea behind the `IDisposable` interface: a deterministic way for resources to be released. While its main usage is when interacting with unmanaged resources that *require* explicit release (or interacting with objects that do that), its usage is not *restricted* to that.

Unfortunately, it fails your last requirement: since it's deterministic, it has to be called by somebody. This somebody would have to be the Asker.

The only solution that I can come up with would be using the `WeakReference` class in your `Giver` object. This allows you to maintain a reference to an instance that doesn't prevent it from being garbage collected (after it's collected, your reference becomes `null`).

Unfortunately, this isn't deterministic. Your reference will become `null` (and `IsAlive` will be `false`) after the object is actually collected, which is not guaranteed to happen at any particular time (or at all during the lifetime of your application).

With those caveats in mind, you could something like this:

```
public class Giver
{ 
    private Dictionary<string, WeakReference> cache = 
        new Dictionary<string, WeakReference>();

    public object GetResource(string resourceName)
    {
        WeakReference output;
        object returnValue = null;

        if(cache.TryGetValue(resourceName, out output))   
        {
            if(output.IsAlive) returnValue = output.Target;

            if(returnValue == null) cache.Remove(resourceName);
        }

        if(returnValue == null)
        {
            returnValue = ...; // get the actual resource

            cache.Add(resourceName, new WeakReference(returnValue));
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You method does not seem to work for me because for any Resource which Giver has given the Asker and while the Asker still has a [strong] reference to it, I would like Giver to return the same Resource reference. Since WeakReference.Target is indeterministically GC-ed, your method cannot fulfil this requirement. Can it?

Comment: @Jake: For any given resource name, the `Giver` will return the same resource reference. There's no duplication here. You want the `Asker` to maintain a strong reference to the resource; you want the *`Giver`* to keep the weak reference. The only difference between this and your requirement is that there can/will be an undefined amount of time from when the last strong reference (all in `Asker`) falls out of scope and when the object is actually collected. During this time, the `Giver` will still return the same instance. This is unavoidable without having the `Asker` signal that it's finished

Comment: @Jake: I'm not certain what you're asking. That block of code checks to see if the instance to which we have a weak reference has been collected (where `IsAlive` would be false). If it hasn't been (`IsAlive == true`), we grab an actual reference to the object using `Target`. If it has been (or if the reference was collected between the call to `IsAlive` and `Target`), we remove that weak reference from the cache.

Comment: @Jake: After that, if our output value is `null` (meaning that either we didn't have it to begin with or the copy in the cache has been GC'ed), we obtain the resource using whatever means you need (in this case, I believe, you said you wanted to get it from the DB), then add a `WeakReference` to it to the cache and return a normal reference to the instance we just retrieved.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I misunderstood how WeakReferences work altogether in C#. (That block of code timedout before i could edit. it is deleted now.)

Answer (score 3):

You could store a [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) to the resource in the dictionary instead of the resource itself. This wouldn't prevent the resource from being garbage collected.

When you fetched a value (the weak reference) from the dictionary, you'd then need to fetch the [`Target`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.target.aspx) and see whether it's null. If it is, the resource has been garbage collected and you'll need to recreate it. Otherwise, you can return the target as the cached resource.

I don't believe there's much control over how "important" a `WeakReference` is deemed to be - I don't think you can say that it should make it as far as gen2, for example. Of course you could have some *other* data structure to make sure that any resource was cached for at least (say) 5 minutes by keeping a strong reference to it for that long.

If you do go for this approach, you may also want to periodically go through the dictionary and clear out entries for which the target has already been garbage collected, to avoid your dictionary getting full of useless entries. If the set of keys is fixed and not too huge, this may not be worth it though, particularly bearing in mind the synchronization you'd probably need.

Comment: The doc for weak references states: "Avoid using weak references as an automatic solution to memory management problems. Instead, develop an effective caching policy for handling your application's objects." To be fair, I'm not sure what use `WeakReference` has at all, if it's not for handling memory management problems.

Comment: @MusiGenesis imo, basically, the caching policy could be "Always check issued references for null before using"

Answer (score 2):

All this functionality is encapsulated in [`System.Web.Caching.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx).

This can be safely used outside ASP.NET and has mechanism for expiration, reloading ...

Answer (score 0):

The `Asker` will have to tell `Giver` that it no longer uses a resource.

At this point `Giver` should remove the resource.

The [`Observer` pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) can help here.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a Dictionary[string,WeakReference]. The MSDN has an example on how to use them to implement more or less the system you are asking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx

Just scroll down to the "Examples" section, where they show how to implement a cache of resources.

WeakReference do not lock objects down, they simply go to `null` when the object they are pointing to is reclaimed by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WeakReference Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) in the `Giver`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with weak references.  Here is an article I wrote about that approach a number of years ago:

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/36286

Comment: Thanks, yours is quite interesting. Unfortunately, does not quite meet my requirements.. Would be useful in other scenarios though.

Comment: @JAke - Could you be more specific as to what requirements this approach doesn't meet?  I re-read your question and this seems to hit on every one.  Either way, it looks like you've found something that works and that's a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Oded's comments, here's the link to the IObserver interface to get you started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx